# What are potential problems when sending emails with a different "from" than actually authenticated to SMTP?

Tags: email, security, smtp

I am building an app where customers can send emails. In order to make that work I have an account to a SMTP server with my own domain just to send emails.

I want my own email to be unknown so when customers send an email I put their email address into the "from" field.

The emails are sent successfully. Some providers like Gmail complain they cannot verify the sender, but yeah, it works!

What are potential problems when sending emails with a different "from" than actually authenticated to SMTP? How would you solve that challenge?

Comment: Sounds just like a spam server, faking senders. Not sure how well that will go down...

Comment: It sounds like a system open to abuse and will quickly get blocked or shut down.

Comment: Why don’t you just configure a noreply@domain email and not literally do what spammers do?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? As others have noted this is common for scammers and spammers. As such, there are lots of email security systems that check to confirm the email's sending server is actually where the message originated from. This is also very well documented online, so I'd suggest doing a bit of research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are potential problems when sending emails with a different "from" than actually authenticated to SMTP?

Just as you already noticed, the provider will complain that it cannot verify the sender.

An email domain can use SPF to define a list of SMTP server IP addresses that are allowed to send mail from that domain (e.g. only Google servers are allowed to send as "@gmail.com"). Even in the common case of 'softfail' SPF policies, a failing sender-IP check will significantly contribute to the message's "spam score".

But if the domain has the default SPF result set to 'hardfail', then a failed SPF check (i.e. your app trying to spoof the sender) **will be enough to drop that message into the Spam folder.**

In addition to that, if the "sender" domain's DMARC policy is set to 'reject', this tells recipient operators that they should **immediately reject** unverifiable messages at delivery time.

For example, @yahoo.com has a strict DMARC policy and if you try to use their domain in your "From:", the messages will be rejected by Gmail (and other operators) as early as during the SMTP conversation:

```
550-5.7.1 Unauthenticated email from yahoo.com is not accepted due to domain's
550-5.7.1 DMARC policy. Please contact administrator of yahoo.com domain if
550-5.7.1 this was a legitimate mail. Please visit
550-5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/answer/2451690 to learn about DMARC
550 5.7.1 initiative. ib1si20883896wjb.147 - gsmtp
```

As far as I know, the SPF source-IP-address requirement doesn't apply when you're merely forwarding messages that have a DKIM signature from the original domain (if the domain  has DMARC enabled), but you're of course not doing that here – you're creating your own messages so you can't put someone else's DKIM signature on them.

> How would you solve that challenge?

If the customer *owns the domain* and wants you to send mail under their own domain, then they will need to add your servers to their SPF records and your DKIM public key to their domain in DNS. That's what the various mailing-list and marketing companies do. For example:

- https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/docs/authentication-delivery/

Alternatively, the customer may provide you with their own outbound SMTP server's details – that's how Gmail lets users bring their own "From:" addresses; it relays those messages through the user's specified SMTP server instead of trying to deliver them directly.

(Originally, Gmail delivered such messages from its own MX servers but used the "Sender:" header to indicate the real sender address – so the messages would have `From: fred@example.com` but `Sender: example@gmail.com`. I assume this works to *some* extent as they haven't removed this option yet, but it probably creates a bunch of additional problems.)

But otherwise – don't do what you're trying to do. Send the messages from your own domain, and just put the sender's mail in "Reply-To" if needed.

---

(And, avoid tricks like `From: Fred via MyApp <noreply@example.com>` as they inevitably end up in recipients' address books and then people keep sending important stuff to your "noreply" address instead of Fred's real address...)